# Site index proposal for useful reference questions/answers

Tags: discussion, search

Often when answering a question it is useful to point the OP towards another question or answer for more information on a particular topic.

I often see such questions and/or answers come up that I think would be useful to reference in the future.  However when the time comes to reference a particular post I often can't find it due to the quite miserably pathetic search capabilities of SE.  Currently I try to solve this problem by favoriting the questions when they come up.  But that doesn't really work well as now my favorites are getting rather large.

So to solve this problem I propose that we start a community wiki post on meta where we list and categorize useful questions/answers that could be used as reference.  What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An excellent idea! (even an exclamation mark.)
I would suggest an  one answer for each subject Example: "Modeling tips", "Cycles Materials", "Python reference" "Awesome answers", etc.

The "Awesome answers" section would be kind of a best of BSE list. Where we not only put, gandalf's answers <sup><sub>:)</sub></sup> but any answer that has been very well received by the community, and seems that everybody should read it at some point.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, I like the "awesome answers" idea too.  I'll wait a little bit to get a little more input then I'll create it.

Comment: What would be the difference between an "awesome answers" section and [this search](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer) sorted by "votes"? That said, it would be nice to have fleshed out references for common questions (e.g. flipped normals)

Comment: @gandalf3 some of the highest voted answers would not make that list. [Example](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1307/2217), this is more of a hidden gem list then highest voted.

Comment: I thought adding some type of categories would work, which everyone can create for themselves. It could work exactly as favourites: one clicks star, and dropdown menu pops up with previously created categories by the user (rss-reader [feedly](https://feedly.com/) works in similar way). But it seemed to me it could be  harder to achieve

Comment: Well it seems this is an acceptable idea.  I'll try to get around to posting it today.

Comment: @gandalf3 and David I've started it up [here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/867/helpful-post-reference-index), please feel free to edit the question if you think it needs improvement, and start adding links!